# how to detect when a new files has been uploaded with apache / php

Tags: php, apache

I need to determind when a file has been uploaded via an ftp account so i can parse the data and insert into a db.

I could do this 2 different ways, either set up a schedule or watch the directory for any change. Either option would be fine.

I'm new to the apache /php space so any keywords that i can search upon would be handy.

Thanks.

Comment: more proper title would've been: `... with ftp using apache / php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you will need a **cron** job. [Here is a good description of cron and short tutorial](http://www.tech-geeks.org/contrib/mdrone/cron&crontab-howto.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set up a server-side cron job to trigger a PHP file that makes the check frequently. On Linux the tool is called `cron`, on Windows `at`. If you're on shared hosting, you will need to check whether it's supported: It will most likely turn up in your control panel software if it is.

Watching the directory would require hooking into the FTP server software, or installing a file system watcher. Both things are possible but very much depend on your server environment (and require root access to the server).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a cron job and any language you like, really.

> Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems (Wikipedia)

Just have a directory which gets filled with files which need to be processed, then process them and remove them on a regular basis. You could have this job run every five minutes or whenever you like, depending on how time sensitive these files are.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check if the file is there, then before processing, move/rename it (filename_[somethingunique]) so that only the current session will access the file.

Otherwise you may end up 2 scripts inserting same data.